Is this really an open problem? The cardinality of the set of games of depth $n$
Scoring Play Combinatorial Games (pdf) says the depth of a game tree is the length of its longest descending path:

The only game with depth $0$ is $\{.|.\}$. The games with depth 1 are $\{\{.|.\}|.\}$, $\{.|\{.|.\}\}$
and $\{\{.|.\}|\{.|.\}\}$. So all games where a player has an option to a game of depth 1, will
have depth 2 and so on. The precise number of games of depth n is currently unknown
and is an open problem in Combinatorial Game Theory.

However, this problem is (seemingly) equivalent to A001699, or the number of binary trees of height $n$. I can't find much literature on it, and I was wondering where else this has been solved.

A game is not simply a pair of two sets of games, it is an equivalence class thereof. The depth of a game is defined as the minimum over the entire class. The game $G = \{-1|1\} = \{\{|0\}|\{0|\}\}$ with $0 = \{|\}$ looks like it has depth $2$. However, it is equal to $0$, which has depth $0$. Equality of games is a complicated equivalence relation to work with, which makes counting games of a given depth a difficult task.
